# react, cannot pass props to next level

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my react code `Home` component

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header'

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <div className='container'>
        <Header authenticated={true} email='test@a.com'/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

This is my `header` component

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  signOut = () => {

  }

  get combination() {
    debugger
    if(this.props.authenticated){
      return (<ul className='nav nav-pills pull-right'>
                <li role='presentation' >Welcome {this.props.email} </li>
                <li role='presentation'><a onClick={this.signOut} >Sign out</a></li>
            </ul>);
    }else{
      return(
            <ul className='nav nav-pills pull-right'>
                <li role='presentation' className='active' ><a href='/sign_up'>Sign up</a></li>
                <li role='presentation'><a href='/sign_in' >Sign In</a></li>
            </ul>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="header clearfix">
          <nav>
            { this.combination}
          </nav>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

How come in `Header` component both `this.props.authenticated` and `this.props.email` are `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you export default 'Header' instead of 'Home' in your 'Home' component. I got it to work when I exported 'Home' instead (check the bottom line).

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header'

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <div className='container'>
        <Header authenticated={true} email='test@a.com'/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Also - I removed the empty signOut function...  My webpack was giving me an error, but I don't think that is what was causing the props to not get passed down.